# Can verb "to fire" replace "to burn" in general, or in a specific context?

Tags: meaning

The following is an excerpt from the Wikipedia article [Mercury in fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_in_fish):

"Coal contains mercury as a natural contaminant. When it is fired for electricity generation, the mercury is released as smoke into the atmosphere."

I first assumed that it's a mistake, but the automatic translation result seemed to be the intended one, as if "to burn" was used. A quick search did not help me find any relevant information.

Is it a mistake, or is it just an unusual but correct way to express this information? Or perhaps there is some subtlety I am missing?

Comment: It's just odd, and may be idiomatic in that particular corner of technology.

Comment: **When coal is fire. To fire coal**. That's how it is said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this definition of [fire](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/fire) (from Lexico):

> Supply (a furnace, engine, boiler, or power station) with fuel.
>
> - ‘liquefied petroleum gas can fire room heaters’
> - ‘We were constructing wooden housing and using charcoal to fire blast furnaces.’
> - ‘As a teenager, to help his parents, he'd work double shifts firing engines in rail yards.’
> - ‘Because Watt's engine was fired by coal and not water, spinning factories could be located virtually anywhere.’

The fact that the sentence contains "for electricity generation" makes *fire* not have any edge in this context over another verb such as *burn* or even *consume*. In other contexts (including all the examples in Lexico), you can't just replace it with *burn* (well, not without being arrested for arson).

Comment: When coal is fired is how it is said in the coal burning industry. Haha

Comment: Shouldn't it be coal firing industry then? ;)